# How to install Boost library on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, boost-python

I want to install latest Boost library on Raspberry Pi, but it kept sticking updating 456 targets when I ran command "sudo ./b2  install", and then the raspberry pi could't work, I don't know how to figure out the problem.

Comment: Do you have swap activated?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command at Linux prompt:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost1.62-*
```

it is not a solution to your problem, but it can help you.